# UITableView in multi-selection mode removes background colours of all subviews in selected cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

UITableView in multi-selection mode removes background colours of all subviews in selected cell. I want not to change the backgrounds colours of my subviews just show the tick mark on selection. I tried to assign cell's "selectedBackgroundView" and "multipleSelectionBackgroundView" to a transparent view but it didn't work. I also tried to reassign the backgrounds of my subviews in "setEditing" and "setHighlighted" functions of cell but it also didn't work. Is there any other way to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the tableView cell Selection to None in the Attributes inspector, or set `cell.selectionStyle = .None` in code.

Comment: By doing this I am not able to select cell. I want only check mark to be visible and not change the backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

for **Swift 3**

```
cell.selectionStyle = .gray
cell.selectedBackgroundView = {

    let colorView = UIView()
    colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    return colorView
}()
```